# Migrating Only DRUPAL7 DATABASE from Microsoft SQL to MYSQL

Tags: database

I have Drupal7 site which is running on Microsoft database,

My current requirement is to migrate from microsoft database to mysql database.

if we can migrate will there be no breakage in the present working site,

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach for this is to use the [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module (aka "migrate_d2d") for this. Quote from its project page:

> ... provides a framework based on the Migrate API for migrating content from Drupal 5, Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 sites into the Drupal 7 site where it is installed.